# Count the last 40 results with criteria in a database

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[EDIT]: I would like to use countif to count the last 30 results with criteria "Jogador Casa" or "Jogador Fora". That is, take the last 30 results of the "Jogador Casa" or "Jogador Fora"

I would like to use countif to count the last 30 results in a database.The column that interests me is E:E ("Confrontos.Casa v Visitante"). At the moment I am using the formula:

```
=(COUNTIF(Database!E:E;""&[@[Jogador Casa]]&""&""&[@[Jogador Fora]]&""))
```

However it takes all the data from "Jogador Casa" and "Jogador Fora" what I would like to do is to take the last 30 players results.

[image: Database.PNG]

I have tried everything and still can't solve my problem.

[EDIT 2]: In the "Jogos" tab it counts in my database how many times it has "Jogador Casa" and "Jogador Fora" my idea is to put a limit, to count only the last 30 that contain "Home Player" and "Away Player" in my database.

[image: Database_2]

Comment: Sorry, you want the last 40 - later the last 30 results - and nowhere I see a formula containing something like 40 or 30 in the formula - but player names, are they relevant for your result, what is the expected result? - here in StackOverflow we show an attempt to solve it ourselves, and when we fail (after some attempts, google searches, ...), then we ask as clear as possible.

Comment: No sir, I want the last results, it can be 30 or 40. What I want is the formula to find these last results.

Comment: Define "last results" is that 20, 30, 40 or 50? What criteria do you use to define "last"?

Comment: I can't create the formula to get the last results. The formula I am using is:

=(COUNTIF(Database!E:E;""&[@[Jogador Casa]]&""&""&[@[Jogador Fora]]&""))

In it, it is taking all the results that contain "Jogador Casa" and "Jogador Fora" what I want to do is take the last results and not all the results.

If you can help me by taking the last 40 that would be perfect. I would appreciate it very much

Comment: I think I could understand you: a) you are interested only in results for the mentionned players. And if there are total e. g. 3000 lines and from these only e. g. 150 lines contain the players, you want the last N lines, N can be defined as a parameter 20, 30, 40, ... 
AFAIK The rest is figuring out an algorithm to do that and finding the functionality in and with Excel to do that - this is not the aim of StackOverflow - it is just you have figured out the algorithm and a (perhaps wrong) formula/code, but it does not work, then you post all of it as question here.

Comment: "the last" are the ones at the end of a sorting mechanism. What sorting mechanism are you using here?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, this should work as you want:

`=((ROW()-1)+4)>(COUNTA(A:A)-1)` (and you can change the +4 to whatever number you want e.g. +40 for the last 40 players/rows).

[image]

The `(COUNTA(A:A)-1)` part counts all the rows of data (minus one to not count the header). This currently evaluates to 9 (10 rows of data in total minus 1).

The `((ROW()-1)+4)` part returns the row number of the cell e.g. in D4 it would return 4. One is also subtracted from this number to not count the header. The addition at the end is what number of last players you want (you suggest 40 but I've just demonstrated with 4).

Putting it all together: for D2, it is the 2nd row, minus one gives 1 and then add four gives 5. As 5 is not > 9, it returns as false (the player/row is not in the last four of the list).

For D7, it is the 7th row, minus one gives 6 and add four gives 10. As 10 is > 9, it returns as true (this player/row is one of the last four of the list).

If this is not what you want then please edit your original post to explain your request further.

Answer (score 0):

Under O365 you can use the following formula in cell `D1`:

```
=LET(set, FILTER(A:B, A:A="A"), lastN, 2, counts, ROWS(set),
 skip, counts-lastN, DROP(set, skip))
```

and here is the output:

[image: sample excel file]

**Note**: It returns an array, so there is **no need to drag down** the formula.

In the sample we are considering the last `2` rows (`lastN`), but you can use a value of your preference (less than `counts`).

The conditions are stablished via `FILTER`. We considered one condition, but you can consider more multiplying them in the second input argument. It would represent `AND` conditions. For example:

```
FILTER(input, cond1 * cond2...)
```

where `cond1`, `cond2`,.. should be an array of the same number of rows as `input` and have `TRUE`,`FALSE` values.